# Determining if this set is closed

Tags: group-theory

The question is to prove or disprove that $$K=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ 0& c\end{pmatrix}: a,c\in\mathbb R^*, b\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

---

I get $$det(A) = ac$$ and $$det(B) = ac$$ in general.

So then $$det(AB) = det(A)det(B) = a^2c^2$$

But I don't know how to know if $a^2c^2$ is is the set K or not. Any help? Have I gone about this the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: just adding to 5xum's answer/hint below: make sure to also check whether the inverse of each element belongs to $K$.

Comment: A subgroup of **what**?? And with respect to which operation? Also note that what you wrote above the separator line isn't even a complete sentence. It's impossible to answer a question, if the question wasn't even stated.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2c^2$ is certainly not in the set $K$, because the set $K$ contains matrices, and $a^2c^2$ is a single number.

However, you also made a pretty strong leap in logic assuming that $\det(A)=\det(B)$. In fact, you should write $\det(A)=a_1c_1$ and $\det(B)=a_2c_2$.

---

But that doesn't mean that $K$ is not a subgroup. In fact, going with determinants in general is a bad idea in this case.

Instead, try to write two general elements $A,B\in K$ and look at what $AB$ looks like. Think about if $AB$ is an element of $K$ or not (if it is not, then $K$ is not a subgroup!)

Comment: Just did as you suggested and the top right corner entry of the matrix I got as AB was $a_1b_2-b_1c_2$. Now this will not always be an integer because a and c can be and real number. So am i correct in saying this is not a subgroup?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is whether the subset  $K $ itself forms a [group](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html) .

It contains the identity matrix. It will be necessary to check closure (is the product of two elements of $K $ again in $K $).  Associativity is satisfied, because true in $GL (n) $.  Finally does each element of  $K $ have an inverse  (in $K $)...